# ListView crashes while fast scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

i created customadapter for listview.Its working fine when im slowly scrolling but, i while im scrolling fast app is crashes. I looked some solutions about this but i dont get it. I think i need to add getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType but i couldnt add these ones properly.

All codes here;
http://pastebin.com/BZB9G9p7

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.example.mete.cocuksarkilari;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final int VIEW_TYPE_STRING = 0;
private final int VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private final Activity context;
private final String[] names;
private final Integer[] imageId;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] names, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row,names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
    this.imageId = imageId;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == 0) ? VIEW_TYPE_STRING :VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    txtTitle.setText(names[position]);

   try{
       imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
   }catch (Exception e){

   }

    return rowView;
 }
}
```

LOG

```
02-01 17:22:51.001  14221-14221/com.example.mete.cocuksarkilari E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mete.cocuksarkilari, PID: 14221
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8087052 byte allocation with 2036816 free bytes and 1989KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:175)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:168)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:51)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
        at com.example.mete.cocuksarkilari.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:47)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:662)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3418)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3801)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3632)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
        at     android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputSta
```

Sorry i give codes in pastebin because its too long and I try this code in Customadapter but it didnt work

```
private final int VIEW_TYPE_STRING = 0;
private final int VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == 0) ? VIEW_TYPE_STRING :VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE;
}
```

Comment: Share your custom adapter and Log.

Comment: i share in pastebin all codes above should i write here? , sorry im new here

Comment: Provide your activity code and error log here.

Comment: okey, i added customadapter and logs, anything else?

Comment: Why are you using getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType()?  It looks like you only inflate one type of layout in the adapter, so it doesn't look like it's needed.

Comment: Normally, im not using getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() methods. i saw this codes in a another topic they solved this problem with getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() methods thats why i added. But i couldnt do it properly.

Comment: oom -> your images are too many and too big.

Comment: @MD if you wonder what to post exactly: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: i have 20 images and total size is just 680kb @njzk2

Comment: @MD like always, compressed size is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

And utilize the `convertView` to conserve your memory usage.

Here's a good article [performance-tips-for-androids-listview](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `ViewHolder` for scrolling fast your list. This is just a hint how that holder needs to look like:

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] names, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row,names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
    this.imageId = imageId;

}

static class MyViewHolder{
    TextView txtTitle;

MyViewHolder(View v){
            txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.YourTextView);        

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row=convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder=null;
        if(row==null){      
        LayoutInflater inf=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inf.inflate(R.layout.your_row, parent, false);
        holder=new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder=(MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }           
        holder.txtTitle.setText(names[position]);
        return row;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the image bitmap you are loading in your adapter is to big and therefore you run out of memory.

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
```

You also don't cache anything. You basically allocate a new bitmap (image) for each item in your listview and therefore run out of memory quickly.

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to handle image loading efficiently. Also you should think about resizing the original image (less quality, less image size etc.) to not run too fast into OutOfMemoryExceptions ...

Comment: thanks but images 720x312 and i have 20 images and total size is just 680kb. i dont think thats why crash there must be other reason for that

Comment: First, fix your adapter recycling code to use `getView()` to reuse the inflated layout. You could also use RecyclerView instead of listview, so that you don't have to implement the recycling layout again. Last but not least, yes 20 images with 600kb might be too large to fit in your memory. 600kb is the compressed version. Android has to uncompress it to a native bitmap. There the same image can be a few MB big. If you scroll your list you basically load the bitmap again and again. So do yourself a favor and use picasso or glide to (async.) load images memory efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at RecyclerView, it enforces the Holder pattern and you are less likely to get memory issues. Also as suggested by Sockeqwe, you should try using Picasso for your images.

http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html (recyclerview)
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: thanks, i will try recyclerview but  i have 20 images and total size is just 680kb